# Partial match of rownames of two files

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following two dataframes

```
masterdf = read.table(text='J   FCCCFC  Translation, ribosomal structure and biogenesis
A   FCDCFC  RNA processing and modification
K   FCDCEC  Transcription
L   FCDCDC  Replication, recombination and repair
B   FCDCCC  Chromatin structure and dynamics
D   FCFCDC  Cell cycle control, cell division, chromosome partitioning
Y   FCFCCC  Nuclear structure
V   FCFCBC  Defense mechanisms
T   FCFCAC  Signal transduction mechanisms
M   ECFCAC  Cell wall/membrane/envelope biogenesis
N   DCFCAC  Cell motility
Z   CCFCAC  Cytoskeleton
W   BCFCAC  Extracellular structures
U   ACFCAC  Intracellular trafficking, secretion, and vesicular transport
O   9CFCAC  Posttranslational modification, protein turnover, chaperones
X   9CFC9C  Mobilome: prophages, transposons
C   BCFCFC  Energy production and conversion
G   CCFCFC  Carbohydrate transport and metabolism
E   DCFCFC  Amino acid transport and metabolism
F   DCECFC  Nucleotide transport and metabolism
H   DCDCFC  Coenzyme transport and metabolism
I   DCCCFC  Lipid transport and metabolism
P   CCCCFC  Inorganic ion transport and metabolism
Q   BCCCFC  Secondary metabolites biosynthesis, transport and catabolism
R   E0E0E0  General function prediction only
S   CCCCCC  Function unknown', sep="\t", row.names=1, col.names = c("letter", "hexcode", "text"))

smalldf = read.table(text ='C   3.01E-04    1.28067155  6
G   5.05E-10    0.04842876  4
AJ  1.13E-02    0.16142919  1
DZ  1.71E-04    0.02152389  1', sep="\t", row.names=1, col.names = c("letter", "probability", "expect", "count"))
```

My `masterdf` is so-to-say a database that has the two important columns `letter` (as rownames) and `text`. My `smalldf` has the important column `letter` as rownames as well.

Now, I would like to match the two tables based on the two `letter` columns.
A `C` therefore stands for "Energy production and conversion", an `AJ` for both `A` and `J`, so "RNA processing and modification" and "Translation, ribosomal structure and biogenesis". Of note, the `masterdf` has a record for every single `letter`, but the `letter` in `smalldf` can be composed of **2+** letters.

I can do so if there's only a single character in `letter`.

```
smalldf$text = masterdf[match(row.names(smalldf), row.names(masterdf)),"text"]
```

However, how can I get the `text` when there's a combination of letters?

My desired output:

```
   probability     expect count                                  text
C     3.01e-04 1.28067155     6      Energy production and conversion
G     5.05e-10 0.04842876     4 Carbohydrate transport and metabolism
AJ    1.13e-02 0.16142919     1 RNA processing and modification | Translation, ribosomal structure and biogenesis
DZ    1.71e-04 0.02152389     1 Cell cycle control, cell division, chromosome partitioning | Cytoskeleton
```

A composed `text` is here separated by a `|`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(tidyverse)
smalldf %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(rowname, sep='') %>%
  filter(rowname != '') %>%
  left_join(select(masterdf, expect) %>%
              rownames_to_column(), 'rowname') %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(rowname = paste0(rowname, collapse = ''),
            probability = first(probability), 
            expect = first(expect.x),
            count = first(count),
            text = str_c(str_squish(expect.y), collapse = ' | '))%>%
  column_to_rownames()
   id probability     expect count                                                                              text
C   1    3.01e-04 1.28067155     6                                                  Energy production and conversion
G   2    5.05e-10 0.04842876     4                                             Carbohydrate transport and metabolism
AJ  3    1.13e-02 0.16142919     1 RNA processing and modification | Translation, ribosomal structure and biogenesis
DZ  4    1.71e-04 0.02152389     1         Cell cycle control, cell division, chromosome partitioning | Cytoskeleton
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get the following error: `Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist. x Column expect doesn't exist.`

Comment: OK I have it now, the following needs to be changed to:`left_join(select(masterdf, text)` and `expect = first(expect),` and `text = str_c(str_squish(text), collapse = ' | '))`